# Symfony Panther && Docker (Alpine) chrome keeps crashing

Tags: php, docker, symfony, chromium, symfony-panther

Recently I've decided to check out the Symfony Panther HTTP Client. I thought it would be nice to integrate that for testing and things.

I did follow the documentation very carefully. I have registered its extension for PHP unit. I can create a Panther client after extending the Panther Test Case - no problem there.

Problem shows when I try to make an actual call. Let's say:

```
$client = static::createPantherClient([ "--no-sandbox", "--headless", "window-size=1024,768"]);
$client->request('GET', '/mypage');
```

These options in the array - I was just trying things out, I thought it might help. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
1) App\Tests\Integration\Container\Controllers\ContainerControllerTest::test_read_container_by_slug
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/lib/chromium/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I did look at the docs and SO for a solution but I can't really find anything that would help me.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is my Dockerfile for PHP

```
FROM php:7.4.3-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /srv/app/

RUN apk update
RUN echo "extension=pdo_mysql" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql

# php-redis
ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 5.0.2

RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && mv phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis \
    && docker-php-source delete

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        unzip \
        chromium \
        chromium-chromedriver

ENV PANTHER_CHROME_DRIVER_BINARY /usr/lib/chromium/chromedriver

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY conf/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini
```

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope, didn't have much time to look at it but I've tried. It might be to do something with how it's being run. Try to run in as a non-root user maybe that will help?

Comment: I changed from php:7.4-fpm-alpine to php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.11 and it worked for me. I don't like the solution, because I don't have the answer "WHY", but at least that worked.

Comment: I really love Symfony but I had to move my project into Laravel - it was taking too much time, constantly there were problems like this one. @Veelkoov thanks for sharing that - I will defo check that out. If changing the system version solved the issue then most likely this is the system driver issue.